# Query String using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to use a query string to pull the first and last name into the url, however the code that I have used does not work, it is not giving any results. I am unsure who to processed.I have tried different ways put I am getting the same result, the query seems fine, however the form seems to be where it is breaking.

```
$(function () {

//grab the entire query string
var query = document.location.search.replace('?', '');

//extract each field/value pair
query = query.split('&');

//run through each pair
for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {

  //split up the field/value pair into an array
  var field = query[i].split("=");

  //target the field and assign its value
  $("input[name='" + field[0] + "'], select[name='" + field[0] + "']").val(field[1]);

}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="element" id="element3528871_1345643">
<input type="hidden" name="MainContent$0$0$hfCallBack" id="MainContent_0_0_hfCallBack"> <input type="hidden" name="MainContent$0$0$hfViewState" id="MainContent_0_0_hfViewState">
<div id="MainContent_0_0_pnlViewForm" class="form_container">
<div class="formHeader">
  <h2 class="formTitle">Query string form filling demo</h2>
  <p class="formDescription"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="display:none;" class="errorSummary">
  <p>Please enter the required information</p>
</div>
<div class="fieldItem type-name medField" id="">
  <div class="fieldItemInner">
    <div class="fieldTitle">
      <span class="title">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldContent">
      <p class="fieldRow">
        <span class="fieldBlock">
          <input name="field_92375_1015030" type="text" size="16" class="textField firstname" value="">
          <em class="fieldNote">First</em>
        </span>
        <span class="fieldBlock">
          <input name="field_92375_1015031" type="text" size="16" class="textField lastname" value="">
          <em class="fieldNote">Last</em>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldInstructions"></div>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- REST OF FORM OMITTED FOR BREVITY -->

   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
search=window.location.search;  
search=search.slice(1);
listOfPairs=search.split("&");
keyVal=new Object();
keyValue=new Array();  
for(i=0;i<listOfPairs.length;i++){  
    temp=listOfPairs[i].split("=")
    keyVal.key=temp[0];
    keyVal.value=temp[1];
    keyValue.push(keyVal); 
}
```